# SOAP help for PHP-Java

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

We are working on building a Web service which the customer can use. The Web service works fine when we test it creating a client-program in PHP. But when the customer calls the service in Java using our WSDL, it gets 500: Internal server error.

Noticed that, the SOAP envelope we get when testing is different and what we get when customer is testing is different. Also our server program logs show, the addfunction() didnt get called when Customer is testing. How to solve this.

The soap envelope we get when testing:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:ns1="http://stage.xyz.com/newcode/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:updateDelivery><ns1:data>9861164345-98611643451391407829-20140219000000-test one-100003767,9861159602-98611596021391408014-20140219000000-test three-
100003769,9861163442-98611634421391407911-20140219000000-test two-100003768</ns1:data></ns1:updateDelivery></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The soap envelope received when Customer is testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><updateDelivery xmlns="http://stage.xyz.com/newcode/"><data>9861164345-98611643451391407829-20140219000000-test one-100003767,9861159602-98611596021391408014-20140219000000-test three-100003769,9861163442-98611634421391407911-20140219000000-test two-100003768</data><hashkey>2604574653</hashkey></updateDelivery></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

### Will these different envelopes be causing the Internal Server error?

Thanks @Mujahed Syed. We installed SoapUI and tested. What we are noticing, the request contains header information along with SOAP envelope. IF only the SOAP envelope is passed as Request in SoapUI, the service returns result, else it returns SoapFault. So What we receive as request:

```
--uuid:6035feb3-d1da-4493-b32b-7146115d0327
Content-Id: <rootpart*6035feb3-d1da-4493-b32b-7146115d0327@example.jaxws.sun.com>
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><updateDelivery xmlns="http://ourwebsiteurl"><data>9861164345-98611643451391407829-20140219000000-test one-100003767,9861159602-98611596021391408014-20140219000000-test three-100003769,9861163442-98611634421391407911-20140219000000-test two-100003768</data><hashkey>2604574653</hashkey></updateDelivery></S:Body></S:Envelope>
--uuid:6035feb3-d1da-4493-b32b-7146115d0327--
```

This as a request returns 
500 Internal Error

```
<faultcode xsi:type="xsd:string">SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
         <faultactor xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
         <faultstring xsi:type="xsd:string">error in msg parsing:
XML error parsing SOAP payload on line 1: Not well-formed (invalid token)</faultstring>
         <detail xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
```

If only the Soap Envelope is given as request to SoapUI, it returns

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:updateDeliveryResponse xmlns:ns1="http://ourwebsiteurl">
         <return xsi:type="xsd:string">100|2604574653|</return>
      </ns1:updateDeliveryResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can we just receive the SOAP envelope in PHP and make the SoapServer call? Or are we going totally wrong in debugging the issue.
Please give your inputs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 error is very general and vague, you have to further investigate this issue. You can try following steps to investigate the issue:

- write a java program at your end and see if it works; examples available here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-soapcl/listing1.html
- Setup SOAP UI and set the SOAP message request to the webservice:  http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/your-first-soapui-project.html
- Install wireshark and investigate the packets: http://www.wireshark.org/

Thanks.